# How can I center this checkbox

Tags: html, jsf

How can I center/align this checkbox and text horizontally?

```
    <h:panelGroup>
      <div>                  
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="deactivate" title="select to deactivate" />
        <h:outputText value="${msg['deactivate/confirm']}" for="deactivate" />                                     
     </div>                 
    </h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: In the future, I recommend to not use `[html]` tag for seemingly pure-JSF questions. You didn't post any HTML code at all. If you want assistance from `[html]` users, you should not be posting raw JSF source code, but instead its generated HTML output as you can see by rightclick, view source in browser. Only then `[html]` users will understand your question and be able to answer it in `[html]` context. Then it's merely a matter of writing JSF code in such way that it generates exactly the same HTML (and CSS) as stated in the answer. I *think* the downvote was coming from a `[html]` nitpicker.

Comment: @BalusC thanks for the recommendation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to apply `style="width: 500px;text-align: center;"` like this :

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" style="width: 500px;text-align: center;">               
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="deactivate" title="select to deactivate" style="vertical-align: middle;" />
    <h:outputText value="${msg['deactivate/confirm']}" for="deactivate" />      
</h:panelGroup>
```

Of course, you must have a width in order to see a difference. Your `div` is not needed so I removed it.

Comment: tnx +1 this helped, but checkbox is still standing a bit higher than text, any ideas? I removed the "block" btw it was centering everything in middle of page, I want it to be left aligned

Comment: tnx actually still not very aligned :)

Comment: @Spring the alignment depend on your CSS arround, you can play with `vertical-align` or `line-height` can't do much without having the complete picture :)